# Apply "natural breaks" classification to a raster symbology in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know how can I apply "natural breaks" to a raster symbology in QGIS?

Because I only see the "Equal interval" option..

[image]

I'm using QGIS 1.9

Comment: Did you find answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to an old question. Up to QGIS 2.18, as you can see in the image below, the `'Natural breaks'` classification is not yet added although the developer team added other types of classifications such as `Continuous` and `Quantile` in addition of `Equal Interval` which was already exist in the old version as you stated in your question.

[image]

You can submit a feature request to add `Natural breaks` classification into QGIS. You can refer to this thread on [Submitting feature request for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208149/63384)