# Submitting feature request for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have an idea of something that would be nice for the QGIS Composer and I think it doesn't exists yet, despite my research. How can I suggest this feature to QGIS developpers ?

I found this that shows the request but I'm a bit stuck at this point : https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

I suppose I'm missing something.

Comment: My idea,for those curious : I would like to suggest the creation of a spacer object, that would have it's own properties and would allow one to tweak the spacing between the elements of the legend. I can already do something similar by using an empty string group or add a non symbol layer with an empty string, by it uses the layer and group settings and has fewer capacities. A spacer item would be nice to add a horizontal bar, an empty space, or any spacer effects one could think about with ascii caracters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To reporting issues or feature requests on [QGIS issue tracking](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues), you need an OSGeo account. Then just login, go to tab *New issue* and in *Tracker* option choose *Feature request*

[image]

Get OSGeo account here: https://www.osgeo.org/cgi-bin/ldap_create_user.py

Also see [QGIS documentation](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html#bugs-features-and-issues) for bugs, features and issues

*edit:*

QGIS issues were migrated to GitHub (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues). For feature request use issue label `Feature Request`.

Comment: That's it... I knew it was something simple ! I was missing the Osgeo account creation step :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could post it at

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

as a feature request. But, as copied from an excellent blog post;

> ...4.
>
> Ask a developer to make the changes for you. This is not terribly
> effective – you’re basically asking someone to work for free, and take
> time away from their family/job/hobbies/social life to do work for
> you. That said, it does sometimes happen, and here’s a few reasons I
> can think of why:
>
> - You’ve build up enough “karma” within the project through other
>   contributions. If someone has been heavily involved in the
>   non-development side of the project (eg translations, documentation,
>   helping users out on mailing lists/stackexchange, organising hackfests
>   or user groups, etc) then developers are much more likely to want to
>   help them out in turn.
> - You’ve got a fantastic idea which has just never occurred to anyone
>   before. By bringing it to the attention of a developer you might
>   trigger the “wow, I could really benefit from that too!” impulse which
>   is hard-wired into some of us!
>
> It’s a particularly interesting or challenging problem, and sometimes
> developers just like to extend themselves.
>
> ...

it's more likely you will get it done (for you) when you hire a developer to do this.

source: http://nyalldawson.net/2016/08/how-to-effectively-get-things-changed-in-qgis/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I did found this link to see the actual existing feature requests but I'm missing the "how to post" part :)  An idea ? (ps : i try to involve myself in the translation part of the project when I have a moment, but i'm not the most efficient translator ;) )