# Auto wrap legend text based on character count

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In QGIS 2.18 there is an option to wrap text based on a certain character. What I need is to automatically wrap my text on the ' ' (space) character IF the character length exceeds the size of my legend box. Question is: how do I get an expression builder in the supplied warp box?

In this example I warped on the caracter '_'
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to wrap a text in the legend based on the number of characters. As you can see in wrap text in the legend, it does not support expressions. There is no expression button beside the `Wrap text in legend` to use . If you want to wrap the text based on space, just hit the `space` on you keyboard and it will be wrapped:

Before pressing the space:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I don't get why they didn't allow for an expression box there. Seems like a very useful tool to haven when creating an atlas or working with many shapes in one project. Thanks for confirming though!

Comment: @HannesLedegen you can add a feature request to the QGIS developer team. Please refer to this answer on how to add a feature request: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208149/63384