# Getting area / perimeter / length while digitizing

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, digitizing, tools

Is it possible in QGIS to see the area / perimeter of a shape or the length of a line **while** digitizing (not just after finishing it)?

I know, I can use the Advanced Digitizing Panel to get the coordinates, angles and length but not the area / perimeter. Labelling the unfinished object with $area shows the area just **after** the polygon is finished.
[image]

Comment: #FeatureRequest

Comment: See how to submit a feature request at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208141/submitting-feature-request-for-qgis and, if you can't contribute as a programmer, I suggest some kind of crowdfunding for it.

Comment: Look this video https://youtu.be/v8WYtAEIDSM. Here explain sides of polygon, but you also can generate a geometry and calculate length and more things...

Comment: This video is more complet:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57nOU660oHk

Comment: @RBenet, that's a nice technique for symbolising your layer, but it does not address the core question here, to display the area and perimeter *whilst* the feature is being edited. I suspect it's reasonably easy to implement, for someone experienced in C++, by extending the existing Advanced Digitizing dialog (shown in the question).

Comment: this plugin should do for you, but I see that there is an open and unsolved problem
https://github.com/lmotta/calcarea2

Comment: I placed a feature request: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50789

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with python, but because there are various digitizing tools you will need to write code for each different tool. Here is an example of how to get the area of a polygon that is being created.
Paste this code as new script in the QGIS python console and click the run button.

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

class EventFilter(QObject):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super().__init__(canvas.viewport())
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.parent = canvas.viewport()
        self.label = QLabel()
        
    def start(self):
        self.parent.installEventFilter(self)
        iface.cadDockWidget().findChildren(QLayout)[0].addWidget(self.label)
        self.label.show()
        
    def stop(self):
        self.parent.removeEventFilter(eventFilter)
        self.label.close()
        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        mapTool = self.canvas.mapTool()
        if event.type() == QMouseEvent.MouseMove and isinstance(mapTool, QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature) and mapTool.toolName() == 'Add feature':
            coordinates = QgsMapMouseEvent(self.canvas, event).snapPoint()
            layer = mapTool.layer()
            geometryType = layer.geometryType()
            
            if geometryType == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
                if len(mapTool.points()) >= 2:
                    geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([mapTool.points() + [coordinates]])
                    crsUnits = QgsDistanceArea()
                    crsUnits.setSourceCrs(layer.crs(), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
                    area = QgsUnitTypes.formatArea(geometry.area(), 5, crsUnits.areaUnits(), keepBaseUnit=True)
                    self.label.setText(f'Area: {area}')
                else:
                    self.label.setText('Area: 0')
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

eventFilter = EventFilter(canvas)
```

Then, type this line manually to activate the area calculation `eventFilter.start()`, if you want to disable it run `eventFilter.stop()`

I think this code will have some bugs, I'm don't know so much about Qt, so the way I display the area is by placing a label in the lower part of the Advanced Digitizing Panel. Another thing to take in account, some how QGIS doesn't let you use the QgsMapTool canvas events in the default tools (Selct, Add Feature, Identify...), so what I did to update the label every time the mouse changes it position, was to install an event filter on the canvas viewport.

Note:
This code is a very simplistic approach, so you will need to customize it for your needs.

For more complex geometry calculations threading will be a good idea.