Measuring Length and Angle while drawing Line in QGIS
i previously use SAS Planet , there is a feature called Distance Calculation, we can measure and turn it into path/line. Is there any similiar function in QGIS?

Maybe https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442604/getting-area-perimeter-length-while-digitizing is still valid.
